# Is this 5th root in the set of natural numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

> Is $$\sqrt[5]{x(x+1)(x^4 + x^2 + 1)} \in \mathbb{N}$$ for some $x$?

I am not asking for all $x$, but just for some natural number $x$?

I don't believe so, but I may be wrong?

Suppose $x=1$, you get $\sqrt[5]{6}$ which isnt natural.

$x=2$, you get $\sqrt[5]{126}$

$x=3$, you get: $\sqrt[5]{1092}$

I might just try a proof by induction. Suppose for $x \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\sqrt[5]{x(x+1)(x^4 + x^2 + 1)} \notin \mathbb{N}$$

But I dont see how that would work out...

Comment: You mean for  $x \in \mathbb R$ or $x \in \mathbb N$? If the first case definitely yes.

Comment: Second case natural.

Comment: @Lebes you have to add $x$ natural number in th body of the question and add a tag "elementary number theory"

Comment: What have you tried? What leads you to the belief that no such $x$ exists? If you include that in your question you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I will put this too, but I tried the first few integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note $(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)=x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.  But for $x\in\mathbb N, x>0$ we have
$$
x^5 < x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 < x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+5x+1 = (x+1)^5
$$
so that $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is not a perfect fifth power, since it it strictly between two consecutive fifth powers.

Next, note that $x$ and $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ are relatively prime.  If their product is a perfect fifth power, then both of them are perfect fifth powers.

Thus, $x(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)$ is not a perfect fifth power.